# Mixing freopen and ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses, freopen

I'm having issues in mixing `freopen` of `stdin` together with ncurses library.

What I do is to reopen the stdin to a file, parse it through flex+bison, then I should revert it back and start ncurses.

Code for the swap is the following:

```
void switchStdin(const char *newStream) {
  fflush(stdin);
  fgetpos(stdin, &pos);
  fd = dup(fileno(stdin));
  freopen(newStream, "r", stdin);
}

void revertStdin() {
  fflush(stdin);
  dup2(fd, fileno(stdin));
  close(fd);
  clearerr(stdin);
  fsetpos(stdin, &pos);
}
```

In my lexer this is what I do:

```
void parse() {
  Utils::switchStdin("./filename.ext");
  yyparse();
  Utils::revertStdin();
}
```

and in the main file I just do something like

```
parse();

initscr();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
noecho();
cbreak();
...
```

Now, if I don't comment the `revertStdin` it just halts when launching, if instead I comment it, parsing does work but the ncurses gui is unresponsive and blinks from time to time.

Since both parts do work when independently used I guess there is some caveat in mixing them in a sequential manner that I'm missing. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: If you need to parse a file with lex and yacc you should open the file and then assign the open FILE pointer to yyin then call your parser.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it. I just wanted to understand what is messing up in this situation..

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one problem, but the important one is that `revertStdin` does not succeed in opening a stream:

- `switchStdin` unnecessarily calls the non-portable `fflush(stdin)`.
- it saves the file descriptor for `stdin` in `fd`, and the file-position in `pos`.
- the file position isn't needed (since terminals don't *do* that)
- `revertStdin` unnecessarily calls the non-portable `fflush(stdin)`.
- it **attempts** to overwrite the file descriptor of `stdin` using the saved `fd`.  That won't work.
- on some systems you cannot assign a new value to `stdin`; it happens that the [GNU C library allows this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html).  If you're using Linux, you could solve the problem using `fdopen`, e.g.,

```
    stdin = fdopen(fd, "r");
```

- if not (more portably) you would use [**`newterm`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) rather than [**`initscr`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr).  Unlike `initscr`, `newterm` lets you specify the streams for input and output.  In that case, you would still use `fdopen`, but not attempt to assign to `stdin`.  Use your own variable and pass *that* to `newterm`.